# table sorter(js) pagination using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, tablesorter

I am new to JavaScript. I am using the [table-sorter JS library](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

I am working on sorting and pagination. My problem is in pagination. I have two problems, as listed below.

1. The pager counts the table header as a row. How do I exclude the table header from being counted? For example, the total number of rows is 15 but it displays 16, since it counts the header as a row.
2. If I click the submit button, the data is retrieved from the database and displayed in table format. The first time, the pager works perfectly, but when I click the submit button again, the pager counts the previous records AND the currently displaying records.

Please help me. I have been trying for a long time.

Comment: Did you get your answer? If not, check out this updated [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which fixes the pager issue (use `td` instead of `th` in the header).

Comment: @Mottie..thanks for replying..its my mistake..pager works perfectly..i included empty <tr></tr> in my table body.so pager counts that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i searched and tried lot,i found the solution for 2nd question.

if you use table sorter(js) then don't add code like

> $("#table-id").trigger("appendCache");

because it will refresh to catch newly updated records at the same time it will also catch the old records(ie..,table rows) so only it confused pagination..